# CRF model making is taking too much time

Tags: nlp, crf, stanford-nlp

I am following this [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a) for making a **CRF model**. I am using following command for making model.

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

Model is made successfully but my training data is very much and it is taking too much time. When I closely observe what is happening in the system. **It is just using only one Core of my computer.**

Can I run this command in a way that it should use many cores of my computer? It look like that it is implemented as a single thread. Is there is a support of multi-threading? If yes kindly share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to download the latest version of the code (version 3.6.0).  It should run multi-threaded by default.

Comment: Kindly update your documentations at this [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml) and write the CORRECT commands according to version 3.6.0
I was stuck in commands finding and found correct command by asking a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566041/ner-crf-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-lo). Kindly update your docs.