# NER CRF, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, nlp, crf, stanford-nlp

I have downloaded the latest version for NER from this [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-12-09.zip). Then after extracting it, I have run this command.

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

This is not working and getting following exception.

```
CRFClassifier invoked on Mon Jul 25 06:56:22 EDT 2016 with arguments:
   -prop austen.prop
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:42)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.argsToProperties(StringUtils.java:942)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.argsToProperties(StringUtils.java:891)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:2994)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

In the folder, **stanford-ner-2015-12-09** there is another folder **lib**, **it already contains slf4j libraries but still it is not executing above command.** I just downloaded and then extracted files and run that command to make a model but this exception is coming. I will be thankful to you if you can help me.

Comment: But libs exist and then still it is giving same error.

Comment: where are u specifying stanford-ner-2015-12-09\lib in the classpath?

Comment: You are missing libraries in the classpath (specifically, [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), but if you include that there will likely be more missing libraries). Just the fact that you have a "libs" directory doesn't mean it's automatically included in the classpath.

Comment: @Tunaki It was a different question. It was not duplicate. Kindly observe the answer and comments for your clarification.

Comment: @HammadHassan I disagree, the answer is the same: the classpath was not correctly set and this is what the linked answer says.

Comment: @Tunaki
Everything was set in my case. Just COMMAND was incorrect.

Comment: @HammadHassan Well the command was not posted in the question. But you can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath for the command.

Comment: @Tunaki
Have a look on 3rd line of my question. Command is already there.

java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop

I am really really shocked why you can not see my command. Really shocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try

UNIX:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar:lib/*:. edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

Windows:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar;lib/*;. edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

Comment: Working on LINUX but not on Windows.

Comment: try java -classpath ".;c:\path_to_lib\*" ....

Comment: java -classpath ".;C:\stanford-ner-2015-12-09\lib\*" -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
I tried this but same exception on Windows.

Comment: I have edit your answer. Kindly accept it. Edited answer is working for me. Place a semicoln after lib/* instead of coln in Windows.

Comment: edit request had no option to accept (may be as many had rejected before) so i did as you wanted to edit.

Comment: Thank you. I am accepting your answer as it is working on both platforms for me.